# Is it necessary to have a separate voting tag for each rating when using Fivestar?

Tags: rating

By design I will have a ratings page with many things to rate - 30 different [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) ratings altogether in the same content type.

Is it necessary to have a separate voting tag for each of these 30 ratings? Because I see there is a character limit on the field in Fivestar tags configuration and I can't input all my voting tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question in your **title** is YES, for reasons explained in Adrian's answer already.

As a workaround to your challenge about "**there is a character limit on the field in Fivestar tags configuration and I can't input all my voting tags ...**" (as in your question details), you may want to have a look at the feature request "[Increase size of admin textfield](https://www.drupal.org/node/1813610)", which is like so:

> When you have a lot of voting tags the 128 character limit isn't enough. I suggest increasing.
>
> Adding a `'#maxlength' => 256`, should do in `fivestar.admin.inc` should do.

The last phrase in what I quoted above might possibly be an acceptable compromise for your case: shouldn't be too tough to implement this change to that **maxlength** ... If you do, consider contributing an appropriate patch back to that issue I mentioned here. That way, and assuming it gets accepted, you would no longer have to maintain/re-apply that patch with future versions of this [Fivestar](https://www.drupal.org/project/fivestar) module.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you need a separate voting tag for each ratings in the same content type, if you use the same for multiple fields, each field will recieve the same rating.

You can make a test, create two fields with the same tag, go to create one node and rate one field, refresh the page and you will see the same rate in the other field.

Comment: Hi, Adrian, thanks for helping me here as well. My problem now is that annoyingly there is a 128 characters limit on the Fivestar configuration where I input my tags.